# Difference between the interface on the android studio and on the emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have create and activity in android studio .

In my work I Depends on `Constraint Layout` , It looks like what I want .

But when I have Run the project in the emulator I have  a different result.

tell me if you have an idea about my problem , please .

This is the `activity in the Android Studio`

[image: a busy cat]

This is the `activity in the Emualtor`

[image: a busy cat]

This is the `XML`code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/row3"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game9"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="320dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.821"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game10"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="372dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.825"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game2"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game1"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.023"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game8"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="280dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.703"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game3"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.353"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.547"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="156dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game6"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.692"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/game7"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="232dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.812"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/point" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#6AC3EB"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/money"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num_points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="100"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/moneyplus"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do you have an idea about the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your emulator uses "RTL" layouts. Maybe It's a device setup with locale set to language which needs to be written/drawn from right to left, some such popular languages are Arabic, Hebrew, Persian, Urdu etc.

Your layout editor in Android Studio shows "LTR" layout.

If you use the following tag in your `Application` tag in `Manifest.xml`

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

It'll stop supporting RTL devices, meaning your app will be shown as is in your emulator, and device with Urdu/RTL locale.

But I'd strongly suggest not doing that. You can instead learn more about supporting RTL devices here.

[RTL support on Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2)

Comment: I strongly recommend against this. IMHO @zahraa should work around the RTL issues he (she?) found.

Comment: Now I want a Quick Selution to my project , Ofcoures I will learn this

Comment: @elcuco that's what I said in my answer, that I strongly recommend against doing that and posted a link where he/she will be able to learn about RTL layouts.